# Amazon SageMaker with PyCharm IDE

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, pycharm, amazon-sagemaker

I'm following [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/run-your-tensorflow-job-on-amazon-sagemaker-with-a-pycharm-ide/) to run SageMaker notebooks in PyCharm IDE (I have PyCharm Pro if that matters). In the tutorial they mention installing Docker and AWS CLI, but they don't mention what to do with them. The instructions just say to install Docker, configure AWS CLI, and run the code. I have Docker and AWS CLI installed on my laptop, and I downloaded the linked [github repo example](https://github.com/cuiIRISA/tensorflow-sagemaker-on-pycharm), but I'm unable to run it on PyCharm. The line `os.listdir(path=args.train)` is throwing the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/project/tensorflow-sagemaker-on-pycharm-main/tf_code/data'

And that's probably because I'm not running the Docker container? I've never used Docker before, so I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run a training job in your machine, instead of in the cloud (AKA SageMaker Local Mode). To do that you need to have Docker running.
I suggest following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/use-the-amazon-sagemaker-local-mode-to-train-on-your-notebook-instance/) blog post which is more focused on the task you're trying to achieve. It also links to a github repo with many examples for local mode.